# MemoryError while creating a empty float32 numpy arrray

Tags: python, numpy

python throw exception `MemoryError` while creating a big float32 numpy array. How do I fix this problem? My numpy version is `1.11.1-py27_0`. below is the code:

```
data = np.empty((22071, 3, 225, 225), dtype="float32")
```

below is my computer information:

```
Memory:7.7GiB, OS type:64-bit, System:Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Comment: You can get the memory usage simply by multiplying: 22071 * 3 * 225 * 225 * 4. 13 GiB.

Comment: If you really need an array of this size, you probably need to use [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) and have 13 G spare disk space.

Comment: from the looks of this your're probably doing machine learning on images. your going to need quite a bit more memory (storing parameter, mini-batches and so on)

Comment: @putonspectacles yes,you are right I am doing machine learning on images.

Comment: thank u @AnttiHaapala I will try  numpy.memmap

Comment: Perhaps numpy.memmap is a match, perhaps not, it depends

Comment: it seems work well using numpy.memmap. @AnttiHaapala

Comment: well, I mean the speed of the algorithm in the end, whether there is a 100x or 1000x speed drop...

Comment: yeah...I see. I will try it and then give feedbacks.